# Refactoring Amortization Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to figure out how this amortization equation can go from what's on the left to the right (ref. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator)). Took the same idea and came up with a generalized equation, but not sure why it works. Can't piece together the steps. Thoughts?

### Amortization equation

$\displaystyle{P}\frac{{{i}{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}}}{{{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}-{1}}}=\frac{{{P}\cdot{i}}}{{{1}-{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{-n}}}$

#### Possible breakdown?

1. $\displaystyle{P}\frac{{{i}{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}}}{{{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}-{1}}}$
2. $\displaystyle{P}\frac{{{i}{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}\cdot{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{ -{{n}}}}}{{{\left({\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{ -{{n}}}\cdot{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}\right)}-{\left({\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{ -{{n}}}\cdot{1}\right)}}}$

   1. Alternate-form: $\displaystyle{P}\frac{{{i}\cdot{\left({\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}}\right)}}}{{{\left(\frac{1}{{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}}\cdot{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}\right)}-{\left({\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{ -{{n}}}\cdot{1}\right)}}}$
3. $\displaystyle{P}\frac{{{i}\cdot{1}}}{{{1}-{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{ -{{n}}}}}$
4. $\displaystyle\frac{{{P}\cdot{i}}}{{{1}-{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{ -{{n}}}}}$

### Generalized equation

$\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}}}{{{y}-{z}}}=\frac{{\frac{x}{{{z}^{ -{{1}}}-{y}^{ -{{1}}}}}}}{{z}}$

#### UPDATE

Not sure why I ordered the equation the way I did–just added to the confusion. Went through the problem again using these steps. The numbers are flipped, but it makes no change in the answer. Thanks to @ross-millikan for getting me to see what I was originally missing.

1. $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}}}{{{y}-{z}}}$
2. $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}\cdot\frac{1}{{z}}}}{{{y}\cdot{\left(\frac{1}{{z}}\right)}-{\left({z}\cdot\frac{1}{{z}}\right)}}}$

   1. Simplifies to: $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}\cdot\frac{1}{{z}}}}{{\frac{y}{{z}}-{1}}}$
3. $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}\cdot\frac{1}{{z}}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}}}{{{\left(\frac{y}{{z}}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}\right)}-{\left({1}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}\right)}}}$

   1. Simplifies to: $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}\cdot\frac{1}{{z}}}}{{\frac{1}{{z}}-\frac{1}{{y}}}}$
   2. Simplify again: $\displaystyle\frac{{\frac{x}{{z}}}}{{\frac{1}{{z}}-\frac{1}{{y}}}}$
   3. Or: $\displaystyle\frac{{\frac{x}{{z}}}}{{{z}^{ -{{1}}}-{y}^{ -{{1}}}}}$

#### UPDATE 2

Posting for completion an alternate-form where I start with `y` instead of `z`:

1. $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}}}{{{y}-{z}}}$
2. $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}{y}\cdot{\left(\frac{1}{{y}}\right)}}}{{{\left({y}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}\right)}-{\left({z}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}\right)}}}$
3. $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}}}{{{1}-{\left({z}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}\right)}}}$

   1. Alternate-form: $\displaystyle\frac{{{x}}}{{{1}-\frac{z}{{y}}}}$

---

*This is a cross-post from the same question I asked [of the Twitterverse](https://twitter.com/billbogaiv/status/1130318079253106691)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation is incorrect.  It should be
$$\displaystyle{P}\frac{{{i}{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}}}{{{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{n}-{1}}}=\frac{{{P}\cdot{i}}}{{{1}-{\left({1}+{i}\right)}^{-n}}}$$
Note the exponent on the last term in the denominator is $-n$.  Then the numerator and denominator are multiplied by $(1+i)^{-n}$

For the second you multiply by $\dfrac {\frac 1z }{\frac 1z}$ then by $\frac yy$
$$\displaystyle\frac{{\frac{x}{{{z}^{ -{{1}}}-{y}^{ -{{1}}}}}}}{{z}}=\frac x{1-\frac zy}=\frac {xy}{y-z}$$

Comment: I've added a "possible breakdown" sub-section in the original question. Does that breakdown look right to you or am I just getting lucky that things are working out? I'm drawing a blank at the rules to apply when dealing with exponents within fractions that include addition/subtraction.

Comment: Yes, that is showing more steps in what I did.